# Accessing Variables in AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, dialog, alert

In one of my Activity there are some calculations and total price will be calculated.After pressing the submit button it should show an alert dialog with Are you sure you want to pay Rupees:XXX...? here XXX should be the final price which I'm storing in the variable.

in     alertdialog.setTitle() I should able to access the variable.

Please help me to solve this.

```
public void onPay()
    {
        getItems();
        int rate = 0;

        if(spare1_item.equals("Tyres") || qty_1.equals("Quantity"))
        {

        }
        else 
        {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Now you can pay", 5000).show();
            db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("mobile_cycle_clinic", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
            c = db.rawQuery("select price from sparelist where name = '"+spare1_item+"'", null);
            if(c.moveToNext())
            {
                do{
                    price = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("price"));

                }
                while(c.moveToNext());
            }
            fianl1_qty = Integer.parseInt(qty_1);
            rate = rate + price * fianl1_qty;
            db.execSQL("insert into spares_items(cycle_id,item_name,quantity,total_price)values('"+cycle_id+"','"+spare1_item+"',"+fianl1_qty+","+rate+")");
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+rate, 5000).show();
        }
```

Here rate is a static variable and in another method I should use that variable in alertDialog.setMeaasge().

```
    public void storeData(View v)
    {
    cycle_id = id.getText().toString();
    if(cycle_id.equals("") || cycle_id.equals("null"))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Scan Cycle",5000).show();
    }
    else
    {
    AlertDialog.Builder pauseBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    pauseBuild.setTitle("Pay Alert");
    pauseBuild.setMessage("Do you really want to Pay..?"+rate);
    pauseBuild.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss");
    //time = sdf.format(new Date());
    onPay();
    finish();
    return;
    } }); 
    pauseBuild.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            // if this button is clicked, just close
            // the dialog box and do nothing
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    // show it
    pauseBuild.show();
    }
```

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: and have u post code

Comment: i dont understand whats the problem. Is the var in the same context in which you are showing the alertdialog. If yes then access it directly if not then make the var static and access it like "Activity.Var"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function to show or create the AlertDialog.
For example:

```
private void showConfirmAlertDialog(int price) {
  AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder();
  builder.setTitle("Are you sure you want to pay rupees: " + price);
  ....
  builder.show();
}
```

If you perfer getting an instance of AlertDialog, you can change the function to `private AlertDialog createConfirmAlertDialg(int price)`, and use `return builder.create();` at the end of function.